# Neat design pattern for geometry type hierarchy

Tags: design-patterns, scala, geometry

I'm looking for a neat way to implement a cool design pattern for my geometry collection. Right now I've got a trait called `Geometry` at the top of my geometry type hierarchy. The idea is to let every geometry inherit the trait and then implement specific code for the specific types of geometry. As geometric objects these geometries needs to implement various methods of course. Take for example the ability to calculate the distance to any other geometry - I've termed that `distanceTo`. The most clean way to do it must be to have a method in the `Geometry` trait like so:

```
def distanceTo(geometry : Geometry) : Double
```

My problem is this: How do I implement this method in a geometry (say a `Rectangle`) without having to type-check for every shape that exists? Are there any handy ways to delegate the requests to the individual geometries?

Cheers,

Comment: You may want to look up "double dispatch" and "visitor pattern". These things do not free you from the need to implement N^2 or so variants of your function, they just make the job a bit easier and let you do it in more organized fashion.

Comment: double dispatch and the visitor pattern are a good way to do it in languages like Java, that lack both (language level) multiple dispatch *and* pattern matching. But the visitor pattern is quite cumbersome and requires a lot of boilerplate code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Scala doesn't have [multiple dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch), your best bet is pattern matching on pairs of geometric objects. Something like

```
(geo1, geo2) match {
  case (Rectangle(x1,y1,w1,h1), Rectangle(x2,y2,w2,h2)) => ....
  ...
}
```

You could then define a convenience method on the `Geometry` trait that calls this method. If `Geometry` is a sealed trait, the compiler will even warn you about missing cases when pattern matching.

Comment: Yes that was what I thought. I had hoped there were a better solution, but I think I'm going to stick with the N^2 variants instead. Thanks for your replies!

Comment: Don't forget to use recursion to shave off half the cases. Only write the code for (Rectangle, Circle) and make the last case in the above match say `case (a,b) => distance(b,a)` assuming the function is called distance. (Circle, Rectangle) is then handled for you.

Comment: @Bart: That's a bad idea, because if you miss a combination it will go into an infinite loop. A better idea to achieve the same effect is to sort the pair by the types of the shapes first.